# Python Django Templates and testing if a variable is null or empty string

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am pretty new to django, but have many years experience coding in the java world, so I feel ridiculous asking this question - I am sure the answer is obvious and I am just missing it.  I can't seem to find the right way to query this in google or something... I have searched through the django docs and it either isn't there or I am just not seeing it.  All I want to do is in a template test if the var is not null OR an empty string OR just a bunch of spaces. I have an issue where spaces are getting introduced into my field - another issue I have to, and will, work out... but, I want my logic to work regardless.  Right now, because my string contains just spaces simply doing this: {% if lesson.assignment %} always passes even though I don't want it to.  I have looked for a trim type functionality that would work between {% %}, but I can't seem to find anything.  I have tried strip, but it doesn't work between {% %}. Can someone please point me in the direction of the answer... some docs I might have missed... something?

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
{% if lesson.assignment and lesson.assignment.strip %}
```

The `.strip` calls `str.strip()` so you can handle whitespace-only strings as empty, while the preceding check makes sure we weed out `None` first (which would not have the `.strip()` method)

Proof that it works (in `./manage.py shell`):

```
>>> import django
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> t = Template("{% if x and x.strip %}OK{% else %}Empty{% endif %}")
>>> t.render(Context({"x": "ola"}))
u'OK'
>>> t.render(Context({"x": "   "}))
u'Empty'
>>> t.render(Context({"x": ""}))
u'Empty'
>>> t.render(Context({"x": None}))
u'Empty'
```

Comment: @PaulP1975: You might have missed it because using `and` in an `if` is a recent addition to Django.

Answer (score 6):

This may not have been available when the question was posted but one option could be using the built in template filter `default_if_none` ([Django Documentation Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none)).

For example:
`{{ lesson.assignment|default_if_none:"Empty" }}`

Answer (score 5):

If `lesson.assignment` is a model field, you could define a helper function in your model and use it:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    assignment = models.CharField(..., null=True, ...)
    # ...

    @property
    def has_assignment(self):
        return self.assignment is not None and self.assignment.strip() != ""
```

Then use `{% if lesson.has_assignment %}` in your template.

Comment: This is an interesting option... I very much like how it cleans up the logic in the template.  I am very new to python and django, so I am still learning the ropes.  Thank you for this suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate it by using the [`cut` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cut) to remove all spaces. But you should probably find out why it contains all spaces in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I intend to fix that fact that it has all the spaces.  However, I wanted it to work either way and couldn't get the strip function to work (Shawn's code above worked).

Answer (score 1):

You can call any built-in methods anywhere in a Django template variable. For example, you can call the Python string method `strip`. So this will work:

```
{% if lesson.assignment.strip %}
```

Comment: Problem: his `CharField` allows NULLs, so a NULL field will cause an exception since `None` doesn't have a `strip` method.

Comment: I do not know why, but the first time I tried to do this it failed... I might have hit the exceptional condition (null)... I can't remember.

Comment: Try `{% if  lesson.assignment and lesson.assignment.strip %}`

Comment: For a foreign key you can use {% if lesson.foreign_key_field is Null %}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do this, from Django version 3.2

```
{{ lesson.assignment|default:"nothing" }}
```

This works for both cases (empty string and None object).

ref link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-default